# Typescript module import spits path in a string form instead of module

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, import, module

Trying to import method from typescript (.ts) file and instead of accessible method am getting path to virtual file (using `webpack-dev-server`) transpiled by ts-loader in webpack.

App has been bootstraped using `react-create-app` (not using Typescript from the beginning) and am trying to introduce TS now.

***constants/dates.ts:***

```
export const MINUTE_IN_MILLIS = 60 * 1000;
export const HOUR_IN_MILLIS = 60 * 60 * 1000;
export const DAY_IN_MILLIS = 24 * HOUR_IN_MILLIS;
export const WEEK_IN_MILLIS = 7 * DAY_IN_MILLIS;
export const NUMBER_OF_QUARTERS = 24 * 4;
export const WEEK_DAYS = ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"];
export const US_TIMEZONES = [
  "America/Adak",
  "America/Anchorage",
  "America/Atka",
  "America/Boise",
   ...
];
```

***somefile.js***

```
import * as dates from "constants/dates";

export const substractUTCOffset = (date: Date) => new Date()
export const addUTCOffset = (date: Date) => new Date()

export const isUSTimeZone = (timezone: string) => {
  =======> console.log(dates); <=======
  return dates.US_TIMEZONES.indexOf(timezone) !== -1;
};
```

Above console.log output:

`“/static/media/dates.92294b02.ts"`

***tsconfig.json***

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./react/src",
    // "outDir": "./build",
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es5", "es6", "dom"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    // "rootDir": "./",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "build",
    "scripts",
    "acceptance-tests",
    "webpack",
    "jest",
    "src/setupTests.ts"
  ]
}
```

***webpack.dev.js***

Pieces of configuration relative to the subject:

`extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".web.js", ".js", ".json", ".web.jsx", ".jsx"]`

```
 module: {
    strictExportPresence: true,
    rules: [
      { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: "ts-loader" },

 alias: {
      constants: path.resolve(paths.appSrc, "constants/"),
    },

"use strict";

const autoprefixer = require("autoprefixer");
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const CaseSensitivePathsPlugin = require("case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin");
const InterpolateHtmlPlugin = require("react-dev-utils/InterpolateHtmlPlugin");
const WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin = require("react-dev-utils/WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin");
const eslintFormatter = require("react-dev-utils/eslintFormatter");
const ModuleScopePlugin = require("react-dev-utils/ModuleScopePlugin");
const getClientEnvironment = require("./env");
const paths = require("./paths");

const publicPath = "/";
const publicUrl = "";
const env = getClientEnvironment(publicUrl);

module.exports = {
  devtool: "cheap-module-source-map",
  entry: [
    require.resolve("./polyfills"),
    require.resolve("react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient"),
    paths.appIndexJs
  ],
  output: {
    path: paths.appBuild,
    pathinfo: true,

    filename: "static/js/bundle.js",
    chunkFilename: "static/js/[name].chunk.js",
    publicPath: publicPath,
    devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: info =>
      path.resolve(info.absoluteResourcePath).replace(/\\/g, "/")
  },
  resolve: {
      process.env.NODE_PATH.split(path.delimiter).filter(Boolean)
    ),
    extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".web.js", ".js", ".json", ".web.jsx", ".jsx"],
    alias: {
      components: path.resolve(paths.appSrc, "components/"),
      containers: path.resolve(paths.appSrc, "containers/"),
      constants: path.resolve(paths.appSrc, "constants/"),
      icons: path.resolve(paths.appSrc, "icons/"),
      models: path.resolve(paths.appSrc, "models/"),
      styles: path.resolve(paths.appSrc, "styles/"),
      utils: path.resolve(paths.appSrc, "utils/"),
      stores: path.resolve(paths.appSrc, "stores/")
    },
    plugins: [
      new ModuleScopePlugin(paths.appSrc, [paths.appPackageJson])
    ]
  },
  module: {
    strictExportPresence: true,
    rules: [
      { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: "ts-loader" },
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        enforce: "pre",
        use: [
          {
            options: {
              formatter: eslintFormatter,
              eslintPath: require.resolve("eslint")
            },
            loader: require.resolve("eslint-loader")
          }
        ],
        include: paths.appSrc
      },
      {
        oneOf: [
          {
            test: [/\.bmp$/, /\.gif$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.png$/],
            loader: require.resolve("url-loader"),
            options: {
              limit: 10000,
              name: "static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]"
            }
          },
          {
            test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
            include: paths.appSrc,
            loader: require.resolve("babel-loader"),
            options: {
              cacheDirectory: true
            }
          },
          {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: [
              require.resolve("style-loader"),
              {
                loader: require.resolve("css-loader"),
                options: {
                  importLoaders: 1,
                  modules: true,
                  localIdentName: "[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]"
                }
              },
              {
                loader: require.resolve("postcss-loader"),
                options: {
                  ident: "postcss",
                  plugins: () => [
                    require("postcss-flexbugs-fixes"),
                    autoprefixer({
                      browsers: [
                        ">1%",
                        "last 4 versions",
                        "Firefox ESR",
                        "not ie < 9" // React doesn't support IE8 anyway
                      ],
                      flexbox: "no-2009",
                      grid: true
                    })
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                loader: require.resolve("sass-loader")
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
              require.resolve("style-loader"),
              {
                loader: require.resolve("css-loader"),
                options: {
                  importLoaders: 1
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            test: /\.svg$/,
            loader: require.resolve("svg-react-loader")
          },
          {
            exclude: [/\.tsx?$/, /\.js$/, /\.html$/, /\.cshtml$/, /\.json$/],
            loader: require.resolve("file-loader"),
            options: {
              name: "static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new InterpolateHtmlPlugin(env.raw),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      inject: true,
      template: paths.appHtml
    }),
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin(env.stringified),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),        
    new CaseSensitivePathsPlugin(),        
    new WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin(paths.appNodeModules),       
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/)
  ],

  node: {
    dgram: "empty",
    fs: "empty",
    net: "empty",
    tls: "empty",
    child_process: "empty"
  },

  performance: {
    hints: false
  }
};
```

Comment: have you tried ... import * as dates from "./constants/dates"; Using the relative path of the file you are getting so if its in the same directory "./" if it is one above "../

Comment: It s one dir above and yes, I've tried it, unfortunatelly result is the same.

Comment: It looks like you might have another Webpack loader that is packaging your TypeScript file as an asset before `ts-loader` gets to it.  Please add the entire `webpack.dev.js` to the question so we can see.

Comment: @MattMcCutchen updated my question. Full `webpack.dev.js` is available now

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, thanks to @MattMcCutchen.

`ts-loader` should have been in `oneOf` section of my webpack config. 
I' ve also explicitly excluded '.tsx?$' from `file-loader`.

That did the job :)

One of possigle general answers to question:

- "why am I getting string paths instead of modules"

is

- "because some other loader is packaging your file before loader you want to use is getting to it"

Thanks for suggestions!